# Grouping Facets in Solr

Tags: solr

In my Solr index I have two different types of items, `A` and `B`, in my index that have distinct fields `foo` and `bar`, respectively, but similar values that I need to group together for faceting.

```
A:
  foo: /* could be "abc", "def" or "ghi" */

B:
  bar: /* could be "abc", "ghi", or "jkl" */
```

It's easy enough to get the facet information for each of these fields separately:

```
http://myServer:<port>/<SolrPath>/q=<query>&facet.field=foo&facet.field=bar
```

Which gives me:

```
"facet_count": {
    "facet_fields": {
        "foo": ["abc", 10, "def", 20 "ghi", 30],
        "bar": ["abc", 3, "ghi", 8, "jkl", 1]
    }
}
```

Is there a way in Solr to specify that I want the fields `A.foo` and `B.bar` to be "lumped together" into the same facet? In other words, I need to make the facet information in the response looks like this:

```
"facet_count": {
    "facet_fields": {
        "foo": ["abc", 13, "def", 20 "ghi", 38, "jkl", 1]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, my advice would be to index the values into a single field. Using copy field directives this would look like this (in schema.xml):

```
<copyField source="foo" dest="foobar" />
<copyField source="bar" dest="foobar" />
```

The would preserve the original foo and bar fields. To get your combined facets, simply facet on the new field:

```
?q=*:*
&facet=true
&facet.field=foobar
```

Edit: it might be possible with facet queries, but only if the list of unique values is small and limited, and you're willing to write a separate facet query for each value. Even then, the results will look different (count per query instead an array of field value, count).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'll do. In the case that I couldn't (politically) change the schema, I would have probably ended up hacking something together with facet queries, but this sounds like the better solution.